# Adding a required in form with variable

Tags: php, forms

I have a variable `$a['required']`, which may be 0 or 1, fetched from database.

How do i add the required in form if only `$a['required']` is 1. I have this kind of form field.

```
<?php echo '<input id="'.esc_attr($a['id']).'" type="'.esc_attr($a['type'])'/>';
```

Comment: You can use a ternary operator, `...type="'.esc_attr($a['id']).'" '.($a['required'] ? 'required ' : '').' />';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator

```
$required = '';
$required = isset($a['required']) && $a['required'] == true ? 'required="required"' : '';
```

Then echo the required variable in your input tag as

```
 $required;
```

Answer (score 0):

check value is 1 and according to it display required

```
<?php echo '<input id="'.esc_attr($a['id']).'"
            type="'.esc_attr($a["type"]).'"'. 
            ($a["required"] == 1)? "required" : "".' />';
```